# package naming in case of reusing library class

Tags: java, naming

Let's assume I am using a library class like `library-package.LibraryClass`.

```
package library.package;
class LibraryClass {}
```

I looked into its implementation and for my application purposes I want to modify that class a little and then use. My application has package `application-package`.

```
package application.package;
class ApplicationClass {}
```

How should I name the package where that class `LibraryClass` should be stored? Should I reuse in my project `library-package` or should I use scheme `application-package.library-package` because I recall I ran into such scheme too.

First one

```
src\main\java\application\package
src\main\java\library\package
```

Second one

```
package application.package.library.package;
class LibraryClass {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this probably boils down to opinions, but let us extract the facts at hand:

- from a technical point of view, it shouldn't make any difference (unless you run into conflicts, because some other part of that library expects all classes to exist *within* those library packages)
- beyond that, *you* are creating something (which happens to be based on some 3rd party library)

Coming from there: the "natural" solution would be to express "you are the owner of this class" by using that `application.package.library.package` naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what you wish to use.

I personally use a scheme like:

```
tschallacka.magiccookies.util.math
tschallacka.magiccookies.util.time
tschallacka.magiccookies.graphics.model
```

etc...

So you have your own 'domain' `tschallacka`

Then your project name. In my case `magiccookies`

Then the group where it all falls under, so you can easily find related classes back. in this case `util` for my utility classes, and `graphics` for my 3d graphics classes.

Then I like to specify a bit more by adding specific packages for the type of tools in that package, `math` for math related classes, `time` for date and time, `model` for all my graphics models helper functions.

Basically it's up to you, and whatever style you wish to use to organize your code.

There are some guidelines/conventions most coders hold to

> Naming Conventions
>
> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces.
>
> Companies use their reversed Internet domain name to begin their
>   package names—for example, com.example.mypackage for a package named
>   mypackage created by a programmer at example.com.
>
> Name collisions that occur within a single company need to be handled
>   by convention within that company, perhaps by including the region or
>   the project name after the company name (for example,
>   com.example.region.mypackage).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking a 'snapshot' of some open source code to embed in your project then a common convention is to use it 'as is', use something like:

```
package <lib-package>
```

Junit does this with [hamcrest](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/index.html), however this may cause a problem as your it is essentially a fork and you're bound to a specific version.  This problem can be avoided if you use the following convention.

```
package my.tld.<lib-package>
```

Since you appear to be essentially [forking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222362/if-i-fork-an-open-source-project-and-make-improvements-in-the-fork-will-it-or-i) the original project, I suggest you use the same conventions.

However instead of forking you should consider using the [Adapter Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html), which will insulate your bug-fix, changes and improvements in original code.